# Magento 2 custom theme setup:static-content:deploy en_GB on production mode does not work!

Tags: magento2.2.2, static-content-deploy, production-mode, custom-theme

I've been doing this for while and having to end up either going to developer mode then production to push e.g css changes or run `setup:upgrade` then `setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` && `cache:clean` && `cache:flush` but this also 99% percent of the time breaks styling and having to run again setup:static-content:deploy en_GB && `cache:clean` && `cache:flush`.

I would think that in production mode one would run `setup:static-content:deploy en_GB` && c`ache:clean` && `cache:flush` would copy css changes from custom theme into magento system pub folder.

Anyone having any ideas and how do you go about deploy static on production mode?  thanks.

Comment: I am use :  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f in Magento 2.2.2.

Comment: @D Singh  on production mode is it necessary  for it work? as it doesn't complaint.